# MATLAB manual error?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I read interesting article about correct memory usage in MATLAB. Here it is: [Link at official website](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/strategies-for-efficient-use-of-memory.html)
And here I see example:

> If your data contains many zeros, consider using sparse arrays, which
>   store only nonzero elements. The following example compares the space
>   required for storage of an array of mainly zeros:

```
A = diag(1e3,1e3);    % Full matrix with ones on the diagonal
As = sparse(A)        % Sparse matrix with only nonzero elements
```

I tried to implement it in my code and find interesting moment:
`A = diag(1e3,1e3)` does not create matrix with ones on the diagonal! It creates matrix of zeros with only one nonzero element:

```
clear A
A = diag(1e3,1e3);
find(A);
ans =
     1001001

A(1001001)
ans =
        1000
```

Ok. I read about `diag` function in help and see this:

> D = diag(v) returns a square diagonal matrix with the elements of
>   vector v on the main diagonal.

Ok! So it really doesn't create diagonal matrix if `v` consist of 1 element! Is it mistake at help?
BUT. One more question: why it works this way?

```
diag(5,5)
ans =
     0     0     0     0     0     5
     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

I expect to get matrix 5x5 with `5` value at (1,1) or (5,5). Why it creates 6x6 matrix and why `5` is a (1,6) element?

---

Some time ago they fix documentation:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Manual: [diag](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diag.html)
you are using the 2nd overloaded version of diag:

> D = diag(v,k) places the elements of vector v on the kth diagonal. k=0 represents the main diagonal, k>0 is above the main diagonal, and k<0 is below the main diagonal.

So your command A = diag(5,5) will construct a matrix where the diagonal elements of 5th diagonal above the main diagonal will be equal to the vector [5]. Thus the resulting value where only A(1,6) has a value.

If you want to have a 1e3x1e3 Matrix with ones on the diagonal try

```
A = diag(ones(1,1e3));
```

Comment: AH of course! Stupid mistake! But what's about help? Is it really mistake?

Comment: Where would it be a mistake? it is exacly as described there. I have a typo in my answer though, it should be A(1,6) not A(1,5). This is because the main diagonal counts as 0. so the 5th diagonal aboove starts with index A(1,6)

Comment: Yep, I get it. But look at this: `A = diag(1e3,1e3);    % Full matrix with ones on the diagonal`. It has not ones on the diagonal.

Comment: @Mikhail_Sam Exactly! [diag](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diag.html) and [eye](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eye.html) are two different things. A= diag(1e3,1e3) will put the value 1e3 on the 1e3 diagonal from the main diagonal towards the top. If this is displayed in your help it is indeed wrong, but I couldn't read it in the online documentation.

Answer (score 2):

The article is incorrect.

```
A = diag(1e3,1e3);
```

does not produce a matrix with ones on the diagonal. The code should instead read:

```
A = eye(1e3,1e3);
```

Comment: Thank you! Can you give me advise now: I want to accept answer, but half of it is your answer and half of it in @FirefoxMetzger 's answer :) Which one I have to choose?

Answer (score 1):

Now reading your question again, I understood it really and have to rewrite my answer. You are refering to this part of the documentation:

```
A = diag(1e3,1e3);    % Full matrix with ones on the diagonal
As = sparse(A)        % Sparse matrix with only nonzero elements
whos
  Name      Size                  Bytes  Class

  A      1001x1001                8016008  double array
  As     1001x1001                4020     double array (sparse)
```

That example is definitely wrong, probably it should be:

```
A=eye(1e3,1e3)
As=sparse(A);
```

Which creates a 1000x1000 matrix with ones on the main diagonal.

**The bug is reported to mathworks**